# How to use AAD-MFA on SQL 2022 on an Azure VM?

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2022, microsoft-entra, azure-active-directory, azure-arc

So apparently SQL Server 2022 now supports the use of AAD-MFA (Azure Active Directory with Multi-Factor Authentication) as an auth method.  ([Source](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2022/07/28/azure-active-directory-authentication-for-sql-server-2022/))

However, this requires Azure Arc, and according to a couple of Microsoft docs ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/azure-arc/automatically-connect?view=sql-server-ver16#evaluate-azure-arc-enabled-sql-server-on-an-azure-vm) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/servers/prerequisites)), Azure Arc is *not* for use on Azure VMs.

So how to get AAD-MFA working for SQL 2022 if it's on an Azure VM?